# Unused arguments when training model using knn

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, knn, supervised-learning

I am trying to create a KNN classifier using the `train` function in caret package, but I am getting the following error:

```
Error in train(trainClass ~ ., trainSet, method = "knn", preProcess = c("center",  : 
  unused arguments (method = "knn", preProcess = c("center", "scale"), trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 3), tuneLength = 20)
```

My code:

```
for (i in 1:50) {
  trainSet <- data[trainIndex[,i],]
  testSet <- data[-trainIndex[,i],]
  trainClass <- trainSet[, ncol(trainSet)]
  testClass <- testSet[, ncol(testSet)]
  trainSet <- trainSet[,1:(ncol(trainSet)-1)]
  testSet <- testSet[,1:(ncol(testSet)-1)]
  model <- train(trainClass ~ ., trainSet, method='knn')
  ...
}
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you change your code to `ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",repeats = 3); knnFit <- caret::train(trainClass ~ ., data = trainSet, method = "knn", trControl = ctrl, preProcess = c("center","scale"), tuneLength = 20)`?

Comment: @jared_mamrot Yes it works, thank you! Did this error occur because a train method from another package being called?